# Changing the behavior of the red number on the Dock

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have two accounts on Mail. I want the red number that appears over the icon on the Dock to only consider new messages in one of these accounts. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Mail does not allow customisation of the app's badge in this way. You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html